# how to find k value for k-means?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using k-means on a dataset including more than `150k` documents but i don't know what a good `k` value is.
I have tried elbow method to find it but the inertia value doesn't change so much.(i am using sklearn).

here is the [image: chart of MSEs]

Comment: could you please post the results you got with elbow method?

Comment: It also depends on the level of details you want. Can you analyze 100 different clusters or do you prefer a high-level 4-cluster analysis ? I think it is more about your use case and your (or your customer's) objectives and not only statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If elbow method does not have a clear answer, then possibly no number of clusters is particularly good. k-means can only model spherical relationships, which might be limiting. You can maybe try other feature representations, such as something based on Word Embeddings.

For a document grouping task, you might want to use a topic modelling approach instead of clustering, like Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) or Non-negative Matrix factorization (NMF).